# Splitting and sorting a multidimensional array for final year project

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, vector, split

I am currently working on my Final Major Project and I could use some help on an issue I am having.

Basically I have an Array that contains 12 other arrays that have 68 Elements inside.

What I would like to do is to get all elements of that array to split each element of all 12 arrays and put them into a different array.

E.G: All of these arrays are inside a main array

```
Main Array = [    

    Array1 = 
          [[ 54,  93],
           [ 55, 114],
           [ 58, 135]] 

    Array2 = 
          [[ 44,  99],
           [ 46, 122],
           [ 48, 143]] 

    Array3 = 
          [[ 47,  89],
           [ 49, 112],
           [ 54, 134]]
]
```

My Target should look like this:

```
X_Array = [[54, 44. 47],
           [55, 46, 49], 
           [58, 48, 54]]

Y_Array = [[93, 99, 89],
           [114, 122, 112], 
           [135, 143, 134]]
```

I can also provide actual Data from output if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you're looking to have here is 2 nested for-loops where, for each inner array, you build two smaller arrays with each having only the x-coordinates or the y-coordinates that you're after. You keep track of which position in the smaller array you're appending. After you build the smaller arrays, you just add them to a larger list of x-arrays and y-arrays.

```
x_arr = []
y_arr = []
sub_length = len(Main_Array[0])
for i in range(sub_length):
    tmp_x = []
    tmp_y = []
    for array in Main_Array:
        tmp_x.append(array[i][0])
        tmp_y.append(array[i][1])
    x_arr.append(tmp_x)
    y_arr.append(tmp_y)
print x_arr, y_arr
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying and helping! :) I have tried your method, however I did not got the output I was aiming to get, Your Solution provided me with '[
[54, 55, 58,]' as the first value, where my aim was to get something like this: 'X_Array = [[54, 44. 47],
           [55, 46, 49], 
           [58, 48, 54]]'

Comment: Hi! Sorry about that, I've adjusted the solution to have the desired output

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much for your help :). I am fairly new to python and not a big fan of arrays. Especially Multidimensional ones. This has helped me a lot. Thank you!